# При клике на пользовательский фильтр новые вопросы больше не подсвечиваются точкой?

Tags: дефект, фильтрация-вопросов

Раньше, когда в одном из пользовательских фильтров появлялись новые вопросы, рядом с фильтром загоралась маленькая голубая точка, а при клике на фильтр, новые вопросы также выделялись этой точкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Теперь точка осталась только у фильтров, а все вопросы одинаковые:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Это какой-то баг или очередная фича?*

Стало довольно неудобно мониторить новые вопросы.

Comment: По-моему, этот функционал официально не релизился. И находится в стадии тестирования.

Answer (score 1):

На MSE заведён соответствующий баг репорт [New activity indicator (bullet/dot) in Custom Filters no longer displaying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383520/339911)

Следим за ситуацией.